# Merge tags [google-play-services] and [google-services]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Yesterday I've edited tag [google-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-services), while today I've found tag [google-play-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-services) (which appears to be the correct one content tag) - and there also is a tag [google-services-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-services-json) floating around. I'd suggest to merge them all three into tag [google-play-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-services), or at least make them synonyms for it.

Comment: I added [google-services] as a synonym of [google-play-services] yesterday - it still needs some votes to be accepted though. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-play-services/synonyms

Comment: @Zoe thought the official description would be ok. it would only lack the attribution.

Comment: ugh [google-services] could be like gmail, maps, etc.

Comment: @DanielA.White when reviewing the questions currently tagged as such, they're almost entirely related to `android`, `firebase` and `google-play-services`... and this additional tag might have been introduced, because the filename of the configuration file is `google-services.json`. for the topics you've stated, there are specialized tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yeah, Daniel was correct. There were 3 questions in the [google-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-services) which was unrelated to Android or Firebase (1 each for Gmail, GMaps and Docs). I removed the tag from these questions and merged the tags.

[google-services-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-services-json) was a bit more peculiar. There were around 20 questions that were unrelated. Most of these were related to completely different services, starting from GMail, Maps, to Sheets, Drive and so on. I cleaned up those 20 and merged that tag as well.

There was one question which I was not sure of, where I left the tag as is [How to fix Fastlane supply missing_email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774577/how-to-fix-fastlane-supply-missing-email).

Comment: thanks for your effort to reorganize this. the one question were you was unsure, could generally be tagged as `google-oauth` and `continuous-integration` related; because for CI pipelines alike `fastlane`, the web-client ID for a service-account is required, which is indeed another kind of configuration file & authentication flow, as the OP there suspected.